# Spring cloud stream with RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

Currently, in my project, I'm using spring cloud stream with rabbitmq. Everything is okay, but the problem is when in StreamListener I set a condition for the message type. If RabbitMQ doesn't match type (Cannot find a @StreamListener matching for a message with id: ZZZZZZ) then this message disappeared from the queue. I don't want to remove this message if the message has a bad type. Is some solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do it:

- Throw an exception if the message has bad type. In this case, the message will not be removed from the queue since it wasn't processed successfully and no ACK was received.
- Insert the message in the queue yourself once you have detected the type is bad.

Both approaches can suffer what is called an infinite loop. The message is processed, it is of bad type, it is re-inserted, and this repeats. To avoid this you can add some policy of reinserting, like: exponenetial delay, or a limited number of re-insertions etc.

But some doubt arises: why is your service consuming messages that it shouldn't? Perhaps you need a specific processor this messages? In this case you can route to the suitable processor.

Comment: On the exchange are sending  all messages with different type (type is in header). I thought if I set condition in StreamListener annotation then spring do that for me

Comment: Why do you need these `bad` type messages?

Comment: I wonder about the design of this application. Because currently is one exchange and a few services which subscribe and each service subscribes only one type of message. I'm not sure but exchange still might be only one but messages can be split by routing key and delegate to other queues.

Comment: Yes, I thought about using a routing key to route these messages to a specfic queue, which can be deadLetter for instance.

Comment: I have a problem with that. Because we have only one topic (exchange in RabbitMQ) and I have a few instances of different application which subscribe the same messages. For example. Message (UserRegistred) is published on exchange, and one separated application subscribe on this message and send welcome email but second different application subscribe on the same message and send information e.g. to statistic service. How can I resolve that problem? Because currently if one service read the message second doesn't see this message.